# Separation of transactions between two different buses in symfony messenger when error occurs in the first one

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-messenger

Let's say we have the following code:

```
try {
        $message = new CreateSomething($data);
        $this->messageBus->dispatch($message);
    } catch (RuntimeException $exception) {
        $failNotification = new CreateFailedNotification($data);
        $this->eventBus->dispatch($failNotification);

        throw $exception;
    }
```

Both of the buses have set DoctrineTransactionMiddleware. Let's assume that during process handlers within `messageBus` we persist some entities but exception occurs - `DoctrineTransactionMiddleware` provides rollback transactions in that situation, so later we land in the catch block in the above code. In the `eventBus` everything is processed fine, so the transaction which is created in the `eventBus` is committed successfully, but entityManager has also entities which have persisted during `messageBus` - so finally these entities are also saved to DB what is unwanted behavior.

I've read in [doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#exception-handling) that

> When using explicit transaction demarcation and an exception occurs, the transaction should be rolled back immediately and the EntityManager closed by invoking EntityManager#close()

DoctrineTransactionMiddleware doesn't do that - I have to explicitly execute `close()` method in catch block before executing `eventBus` dispatch - then I rid off unwanted entities from `messageBus`. Maybe I understand wrong the idea and it just works like that OR DoctrineMiddleware misses execute close() method. IMO DoctrineTransactionMiddleware should provide such execution without developer intervention.